# 'npm install' commands is not executed successfully throwing some python error

Tags: python, node.js, laravel, npm

I'm running npm install on windows to do installation of node modules, but I'm getting this error and I have no idea what it is and I can't find anything related. Need some help for solving this issue.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\mycomputer\Desktop\project\node_modules\node-libcurl
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.3.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\mycomputer\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\mycomputer\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\mycomputer\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\node-libcurl\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\mycomputer\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\mycomputer\\.node-gyp\\15.3.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\mycomputer\\.node-gyp\\15.3.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\mycomputer\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\mycomputer\\.node-gyp\\15.3.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\mycomputer\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\node-libcurl',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\mycomputer\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\node-libcurl\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp: Undefined variable module_name in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\mycomputer\Desktop\project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:277:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\mycomputer\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\mycomputer\Desktop\project\node_modules\node-libcurl
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure without more detail, but it looks like the problem may be that one of your node modules is using your system python, and your system python is **version 2**, which is currently unsupported (obsolete) in almost every use case. I'd **recommend trying to install python3** on your system and see if that fixes things.